# Please identify this moth from Bangladesh

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

Sorry for bad resolution of the picture. This picture is taken from JU campus, Savar.
[image: unidentified moth]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I have found the identification. It is a planthopper from ricaniidae family. Most likely ***Ricanula stigmatica***.

[image: Ricanula stigmatica]

**Image source**: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricanula_stigmatica